# gulp package-solution --ship not building sppkg file

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

A Spfx webpart was made , it was build by  using **gulp bundle --ship** command with no error then  **gulp package-solution --ship** was entered in cmd to get sppkg file but 3 errors came

```
Error - Error: The webparts manifests list is empty. Please ensure you have 
done a build and that your config file is pointed at the correct folder.
Error - Error: The webparts manifests list is empty. Please ensure you have 
done a build and that your config file is pointed at the correct folder.
at Object.createPackage [as default] (C:/Users/PolestarUser/Desktop/reportStatusWebpart/report-status-webpart/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-build-core-tasks/lib/packageSolution/packageSolution/createPackage.js:25:19)
at DestroyableTransform.gulp.src.pipe.through2.obj [as _flush] (C:/Users/PolestarUser/Desktop/reportStatusWebpart/report-status-webpart/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-build-core-tasks/lib/packageSolution/PackageSolutionTask.js:112:36)
at DestroyableTransform.prefinish (C:/Users/PolestarUser/Desktop/reportStatusWebpart/report-status-webpart/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:138:10)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:208:7)
at prefinish (C:/Users/PolestarUser/Desktop/reportStatusWebpart/report-status-webpart/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:619:14)
at finishMaybe (C:/Users/PolestarUser/Desktop/reportStatusWebpart/report-status-webpart/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:627:5)
at endWritable (C:/Users/PolestarUser/Desktop/reportStatusWebpart/report-status-webpart/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:638:3)
at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (C:/Users/PolestarUser/Desktop/reportStatusWebpart/report-status-webpart/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:594:41)
at DestroyableTransform.onend (C:/Users/PolestarUser/Desktop/reportStatusWebpart/report-status-webpart/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:523:10)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:208:7)
at C:/Users/PolestarUser/Desktop/reportStatusWebpart/report-status-webpart/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:965:16
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
Error - 'package-solution' sub task errored after 199 ms
Some manifests were found in '*.json' , but were not valid. Ensure paths.manifestsMatch is correct
```

Comment: how about doing a `1) gulp build 2)  gulp bundle --ship  and then 3) gulp package-solution --ship` commands and check ?

Comment: hey gautam I tried this,it is still not working

Comment: Try this `gulp clean` then `gulp build --ship`, `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship`

Comment: hey bharat it is also not working

Comment: There's a problem with your config.json.

Comment: Bharat, your comment worked for me. My documentation only had three of the four commands, thank you

Answer (score 1):

problem was in my npm version which was 5.6.0 so i downgraded it to 3.0.0 and build again